# How to install the latest version of VLC (2.1.2) on Ubuntu 12.04?

Tags: 12.04, upgrade, video, vlc, hd-video

I need play video in ultra-hd 4K definition (3840×2160 pixels) and my favorite player is VLC.

In Ubuntu 12.04 LTS the latest available version of VLC is 2.0.8 which does not have support for this type of videos and need to update to the latest available version of VLC (2.1.2).

How I can install the latest stable version of VLC on Ubuntu 12.04?

Comment: no, it is not a duplicate... there is no response about how to update to the latest stable version of VLC

Answer (score 4):

There's now a third-party PPA that provides the most recent build of VLC for Ubuntu 12.04, Ubuntu 12.10, Ubuntu 13.04, Ubuntu 13.10.

Press Ctrl+Alt+T on keyboard to open the terminal. When it opens, run the commands below one by one:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:djcj/vlc-stable

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install vlc
```

via: http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2014/02/install-vlc-2-1-2-ubuntu-12-04/

Comment: that still works in 14.04 to get the not-yet-stable 2.2 when ppa:videolan/master-daily gives errors

Comment: the ppa doesn't work anymore

Answer (score 3):

Check [the official VLC PPA](https://launchpad.net/~videolan).

For the current stable version of VLC that is `ppa:videolan/stable-daily`

Add it to your system

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:videolan/stable-daily
```

Update and upgrade / install VLC

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install vlc
```

To install the latest version add the daily updated

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:videolan/master-daily
```

Note: The VLC Stable PPA contains the same version of Ubuntu 12.04 repositories (2.0.8) and VLC Master PPA contains 2.2.0 (development version).

Comment: The VLC PPA that contains the same version of Ubuntu 12.04 repositories (2.0.8)

Comment: See the edited answer

Comment: I need the latest stable version (2.1.2) not the development version (2.2.0)

Answer (score 0):

The [VLC stable PPA[image: Launchpad logo]](https://launchpad.net/%7Evideolan/+archive/stable-daily) **does not** contain the 2.1.2 version for any release apart from Trusty, which is still in development.

According to the PPA's description, this is intended:

> This PPA contains daily builds from the latest VLC maintenance branch.
>
> This PPA is used for test building new and upcoming point releases of
> VLC that can get into Ubuntu through stable release updates (SRU) or
> security updates. You **don't find major version updates** in this PPA
> (e.g. no update from 2.1.x to 2.2.x).
>
> <sub>From the [PPA description](https://launchpad.net/%7Evideolan/+archive/stable-daily), emphasis mine</sub>

You may need to locate another PPA with the latest stable.

Even the VLC [download for Ubuntu page](http://www.videolan.org/vlc/download-ubuntu.html) doesn't give instructions to get the latest version.

> Ubuntu includes whichever VLC version was the latest at the time the Ubuntu release was frozen (typically about two months before the official Ubuntu upgrade).
> Afterward, you can still get security and critical bug fixes, but no further major VLC version updates until the next Ubuntu release.
>
> If you need a more recent version, please consider upgrading Ubuntu.
>
> <sub>From [VLC media player for Ubuntu](http://www.videolan.org/vlc/download-ubuntu.html)</sub>

---

#### Manually compiling

This is not the best way, unless you really have a need for the latest you should just be happy with the older and stable version.

You may try to download the source from [here](http://www.videolan.org/vlc/download-sources.html), compile then install if you're so inclined.

Download the source `tar.xz` file, there should be a `README` with instructions.

Comment: can not simply update the necessary packages in the repositories of Ubuntu 12.04. Or at least how to compile it by hand? I can not enjoy a full Ubuntu system having so many complications for a simple program

Comment: @lozanotux The repos cannot simply be 'updated' because they are frozen and only updated for security fixes. See my edits about compiling.

Comment: Sure, but I need some kind of guide or instructions as I need more recent libraries to compile

Comment: @lozanotux Can't help you there, I don't have much experience compiling but  there should be a README with instructions in the source package.

Comment: Definitely can not help me, I expected more from AskUbuntu. I know what a README file and what are the steps... need some updated libraries to compile VLC and there is no PPA that provides this libraries. At the end, after all Ubuntu fails to be a fully usable operating system (at least not in this way).

Answer (score 0):

[Nate Muench](https://launchpad.net/~n-muench) has long maintained repos for VLC releases that haven't made it to the "stable" repos. Currently he has the following, both containing VLC 2.1.2:

- https://launchpad.net/~n-muench/+archive/vlc2 (for Precise)
- https://launchpad.net/~n-muench/+archive/vlc (for Saucy)

Comment: Thanks for sharing this repo. Unfortunately it appears as though the VLC build for 12.04 failed. Upgrading won't be possible at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

I downloaded the VLC2.1.5.tar.gz, unpacked it in a subfolder of my homedir. I ran the usual ./configure and of course had to tackle all missing libraries. I left Synaptic open to search for the missing files, installed the -dev and repeated the ./configure until I was invited to run the 'make', closed Synaptic and ran a 'sudo make install'. It created the vlc executable shortcut. It left me with two versions of VLC that both run properly as far as I can see. I too have reasons not (yet) to upgrade to 14.04. It takes time to compile but it was worth the effort.

Peter