# I cant install vlc in ubuntu 14.04

Tags: software-installation, vlc

first I typed this: `sudo apt-get update`
at the end of the progress, this is shown:

```
W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/pcf/miro-releases/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

then I run: `sudo apt-get upgrade` and sussessfully upgraded. after this, from here, (https://www.videolan.org/vlc/download-ubuntu.html) I run:

```
sudo apt-get install vlc browser-plugin-vlc
```

and it also has been installed. Then, I go here([How to install the latest version of VLC (2.1.2) on Ubuntu 12.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/405165/how-to-install-the-latest-version-of-vlc-2-1-2-on-ubuntu-12-04)) and run them:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:videolan/stable-daily
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install vlc
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:videolan/master-daily
```

when all are done, I tried to open a video file. I chose "open with vlc media player", but nothing happened, I clicked several times, but nothing changed. 
Now please tell me, what should I do?

ok, thank you so much. I opened a terminal and run "vlc". then it comes. I dont know what it is.

```
desktop:~$ vlc
VLC media player 2.1.6 Rincewind (revision 2.1.6-0-gea01d28)
[0x8166158] main libvlc: Running vlc with the default interface. Use 'cvlc' to use vlc without interface.
[0x81f54c8] skins2 interface error: no suitable dialogs provider found (hint: compile the qt4 plugin, and make sure it is loaded properly)
[0x81f54c8] skins2 interface error: cannot instantiate qt4 dialogs provider
[0x81f54c8] [cli] lua interface: Listening on host "*console".
VLC media player 2.1.6 Rincewind
Command Line Interface initialized. Type `help' for help.
>
```

Comment: If you can live with the fact, that you won't have the newest version... VLC is also in Software Centre. It installs without any trouble.

Comment: Oh, I was wrong, the version in SC is 2.2.0, or at least I don't remember downloading it elsewhere...

Comment: The warnings you list first have nothing to do with VLC. Look at [this question] on how to get rid of this warning. Additionally, it is not necessary to first install the old version from the official repository and then later update to the newer PPA version. You could have omitted the installation before the `add-apt-repository` commands. First add all needed PPAs, then run the install command. Not the other way round. To troubleshoot your problem: Open a terminal and run `vlc` from there. It will give you error messages you can post here ([edit] your question).

Comment: @ByteCommander [which question?] ([could be this one](http://askubuntu.com/q/65911/178596))

Comment: @Wilf Oh yes, indeed! ^_^ I totally forgot to add the link. Stupid me...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The vlc master ppa is basically dead, no new builds since mid march of the current dev vlc so it's worthless. So remove from sources -

```
sudo add-apt-repository -r ppa:videolan/master-daily
```

The stable ppa is outdated for 14.04 so doesn't matter if you keep or remove, maybe they'll do a new build, maybe not. To remove like above -

```
sudo add-apt-repository -r ppa:videolan/stable-daily
```

Now update your sources -

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Remove vlc completely -

```
sudo apt-get purge vlc-data
```

Re install vlc, either from command below or from software-center

```
sudo apt-get install vlc
```

Remove current config for vlc, copy & paste so no mistake with command!

```
rm -rf ~/.config/vlc
```

Now vlc should open fine..

Comment: didnt work !!!!!

Comment: If it didn't work then please elaborate. Or try opening vlc from terminal as such - `vlc -Iqt4`